# Show real time position of a specific device

Tags: android, ios, sockets, publish-subscribe

I would create an app (on Android now and subsequently on IOS) that could track position in real time of a specific device. 
something like:

- user1 get a list of nearby users
- user1 "ask" user2 to get his position
- user2 accept so user1 could see his position

Now i would know what's the best way to track position for ensure compatibility between various mobile OS, because i know only android programming, not IOS.

with my knowledge, i've think three possible solutions:

- Create socket between user1 and user2 (also if they have different os) for get position info
- Create a publish-subscriber server where user1 and user2 could communicate
- Create a simple database with current position of user2 and retrieve it at regular inetrval

Any other suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to create a socket between two phones, because they don't have a constant IP address.  Pretty much the only way to do this is to have both phones register with a we server, and have the server push updates to all clients, or for clients to poll for updates from the server.

As an aside, these kind of apps exist already.  There's dozens of them, one even from Google.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that this kind of app already exist, but this functions will be only a part of my app, not the only one! :)
So the best way seems to be my third option